# Vuelidate make input field 1 or input field 2 required "Or" validator?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I am trying to implement Vuelidate into my Vue Form. I have 2 fields, Phone Number and Email. I want to check if either of them is set. I assume this is the "Or" Validator, but I can not find any examples how to implement it.I found something on here and tried to copy it, but get
phone not defined. I also found something on GitHub, but again this was not working. I justy dont understand how this is supposed to work. So Validation should pass if either is entered and only fail if both fields are empty. Am I understanding the Or Validator correct and if so, how is it supposed to work? I hope someone can give me a hint. Thank you very much in advance.

```
data: () => ({

form: {
  email: '',
  phone:'',
},
}),

validations: {
  form: {

    email:{
      required,
      mycustomval: or(phone)
    },
    phone:{
     required
    },
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now got it to work. The problem was that I used form:{} so I need to use this.form.phone or this.form.mobile to get the value.

```
export default {

mixins: [validationMixin],
data: () => ({
  form: {
    email: '',
    phone:'',
  },
}),
```

So to get it to work I have to use:

```
  validations: {

    form: {
      email:{
        required (v) {
        return this.form.phone|| required(v)
      }},

      phone: {
        required (v) {
          return this.form.email|| required(v)
      }},
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `form` object by accessing second params of the required function

```
validations: {
    form: {
      email:{
        required (v, form) {
          // { email: '', phone: '' }
          console.log(form)
          return form.phone || required(v)
        }
      },
     },
   },
```

This is especially useful if you are working with array of object validation.

```
data() {
  return {
    data: [{ email: '', isCurrentUserMaxLengthEmail: 17 }],
  };
},
```

and the validation would be

```
validations: {
    data: {
      $each: {
        email: {
          maxLength (v, obj) {
            // { email: '', isCurrentUserMaxLengthEmail: 17 }
            console.log(obj)
            return obj.isCurrentUserMaxLengthEmail >= v.length
          },
        },
      },
     },
   },
```

Comment: Thank you Savano, I got it to work already so unfortunately I can not try out your solution right this minute, but Thank you for suggesting it, it might help someone else.